# Using .NET GZipStream Class with Mono

Tags: c#, .net, mono, gzip, gzipstream

I'm trying to build an example from [GZipStream Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx). With the command `gmcs gzip.cs`, I got error messages. gzip.cs is the same source from the msdn.

It seems that I need to add reference when compiling. What's missing?

```
gzip.cs(57,32): error CS1061: Type `System.IO.FileStream' does not contain a definition for `CopyTo' and no extension method `CopyTo' of type `System.IO.FileStream' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.1/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
gzip.cs(86,40): error CS1061: Type `System.IO.Compression.GZipStream' does not contain a definition for `CopyTo' and no extension method `CopyTo' of type `System.IO.Compression.GZipStream' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.1/lib/mono/gac/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warnings
```

### SOLVED

I should use 'dmcs', not 'gmcs' in order to use .NET 4 functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Stream.CopyTo` only arrived in .NET 4 - it may not be in Mono yet (or perhaps you need a more recent version).

It's easy to write a similar extension method though:

```
public static class StreamExtensions
{
    public static void CopyTo(this Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using mono 2.10.2 which is the newest one.

Comment: @prosseek: Then presumably they haven't included it yet.

Comment: I found that I didn't use the dmcs that supports .NET 4.0. It compiles OK with dmcs. Thanks for the help.